# WinForm app using EF Data First getting error on Vista

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first, windows-vista

I have a simple form that contains  a  Binding Source created with Entity Framework, Code First. Anything works fine on the PC used to create the program. After creating the setup, I want to use the program on a PC with Windows Vista and when I execute it I get this error message:

*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

The application starts normally, but the data grid does not fill with data!
Could someone help me, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about database credentials. after setup in vista pc check database connection. It must be same as your pc that you created the program.

Comment: Ok, but how can I change the database connection on vista pc? I don't have any program to handle the database file.

Comment: Issue solved. I've just defined the connection string in config file, giving the same name called in the context class.
Thanks for your help!